# How to refer to a new array object

Tags: java, arrays

I created a List of boxes from the box class like such:

```
private static final List<Box> shapes = new ArrayList<Box>(16);
```

I have a keyevent method that calls the class to change the box size.

```
if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_1 && Keyboard.getEventKeyState()) {
    if (Box.getSize() == 0){
         shapes.add(new Box(0, 463, "r"));
    }
}
```

For the `getSize()` method used here, I need to call it only for the box created. I want to basicly create the box at a certain size and use methods for only this box that was created. How can I make this new box created in my ArrayList call methods from the box class on its' own. Something like this fake code: `this.box.getSize() = 1;`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this question is more suited for Stack Overflow than here... This site is intended for more conceptual questions about programming and software development more than code help.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "on its own"?

Comment: can you post the code where the box is created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an *instance* of `Box` for the code to work. At some point you should have something like this:

```
Box box = new Box(param1, param2, param3);
```

Then you can call methods on that particular `Box` object (and notice the lowercase):

```
box.getSize()
```

In your code, you have this (and notice the uppercase):

```
Box.getSize()
```

That works when calling an `static` method, a method that's common to *all* instances of `Box`, but it's not the correct way to call an *instance* method - one that's particular to an object which is an instance of `Box`.

Answer (score 0):

> I created a List of boxes from the box class like such:
>
> ```
> private static final List<Box> shapes = new ArrayList<Box>(16);
> ```

First of all, that line of code doesn't create any boxes. It creates a list that *can* hold boxes, but it starts out empty. The `16` in the constructor to the ArrayList is only the initial capacity of its internal array -- it is only a performance optimization to reduce internal memory reallocation later. The *size* of the new ArrayList is `0`.

This is different to plain arrays, where the size is fixed and is specified in its construction; e.g., `Box[] shapes = new Box[16];`. However, this also doesn't create any actual boxes; just a Box array full of `null`s.

Your list won't contain any boxes until you do something like:

```
Box aBox = new Box();
shapes.add(aBox);
```

I'm not quite sure what this is meant to do:

```
if (Box.getSize() == 0){
```

If you want to know about how many boxes are in the list, then you can do:

```
if (shapes.size() == 0) {
```

Or:

```
if (shapes.isEmpty()) {
```

If you want to call a `getSize()` method on some specific box, you'll have to create that box first.